# How to use certificate in tomcat 8?

Tags: ssl-certificate, tomcat8

I have three certificate file :

```
ca_bundle.crt
certificate.crt
certificate.csr
```

How to use these files in tomcat 8 and install certificates?

Comment: Do you have keystore file

Comment: No. I have these files

Answer (score 0):

You have to enter the path to these files in the tomcat's server.xml file, under the ssl connector section, with the exception of the .csr file, which is not used. Instead, you need to also add the path to the private key file. You have to restart tomcat to apply the changes, when using this method. Refer to the server.xml manual of tomcat for more details. I 'm not sure, if there is a dynamic way of adding certificates to the running instance of tomcat.

You need to create a combined certificate file. Make a copy of ca_bundle.crt and open it with a text editor, then paste the contents of certificate.crt to the end of this file and save it as combined_ca_cert_file.crt.

See below an example of server.xml file, ssl connector section:

```
<Connector port="8443" maxHttpHeaderSize="8192" maxThreads="150" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11AprProtocol"
            minSpareThreads="25" maxSpareThreads="75" enableLookups="false"
            disableUploadTimeout="true" acceptCount="100" connectionTimeout="20000" maxPostSize="-1" scheme="https" 
            secure="true" SSLEnabled="true" sslProtocol="TLSv1+TLSv1.1+TLSv1.2"
            SSLCertificateFile="combined_ca_cert_file.crt"
            SSLCACertificateFile="combined_ca_cert_file.crt"
            SSLCertificateKeyFile="private_key.txt"
            SSLVerifyClient="none"
    />
```

None of the files you mention (based on their extensions) seems to be a private key file. You must have generated one when generating certificates. You must have saved the private key file then. The private key file contains a text that starts with something like ---PRIVATE KEY...
If you lost a private key file, the certificates are useless and you need to generate them again. You can use the .csr (certificate signing request) file to generate the private key and certificates again.

Comment: which one is the private key file?